# Platform compatibility of Chrome Stand Alone Apps

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm doing some reading on Google Chrome stand-alone applications and I see they are distributed like Chrome Extensions, and by all means, they seem work just like Chrome Extensions, so I assume they will run on the major platforms that run Chrome, like Linux, Mac and Win. But, I don't see any official word on the supported platforms, is there such a reference point?

Answer (score 3):

Chrome packaged apps are available in ChromeOS, Linux, Mac and Windows. You are right, there is no explicit information about it in our online documentation, but that's unintentional.

In fact, you can already run Chrome packaged apps in all platforms mentioned above. The way they are launched - through the Chrome New Tab - is going to change and will behave more like native apps. The current launching method is for developer preview only.